# hibernate mapping foreign-key within primary key to alternate key

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, dictionary, foreign-keys

I have 3 tables:

```
Account
{
Long account_id; // primary key, alternate key field 1
Long client_id;  // alternate key field 2
...
}

Admin
{
Long office_id;  // primary key field 1
Long account_id; // primary key field 2
Long client_id;
}

Office
{
Long office_id; // primary key
...
}
```

So the Admin table references Account table by alternate key (of account_id, client_id). I try to write mapping for it but cant understand how.

I have now:

```
<class name="Account" table="Account">
    <id name="id">
        <column name="account_id" not-null="true"/>
    </id>
    <properties name="account_ak1" unique="true">
        <property name="id" column="account_id" insert="false" update="false"/>
        <property name="client" column="client_id" insert="false" update="false"/>
    </properties>
    <many-to-one name="client" class="Client" column="client_id" lazy="false" fetch="join"/>
...
</class>

<class name="Admin">
    <composite-id name="id" class="KeyPair">
        <key-many-to-one name="t1" class="Office" column="office_id" lazy="false"/>
        <key-many-to-one name="t2" class="Account" lazy="false" column="account_id"/>
    </composite-id>
    <many-to-one name="account" class="Account" not-null="true" insert="false" update="false" lazy="false" fetch="join" property-ref="account_ak1">
        <column name="account_id"/>
        <column name="client_id"/>
    </many-to-one>
</class>
```

The problem is that i cant set client_id in sql update/insert this way and i cant set only account_id to insert/update false neither within composite-id nor within many-to-one. 
Also, i tried to include all the fields of Account in primary key.

```
    <composite-id name="id" class="KeyPair">
        <key-many-to-one name="t1" class="Office" column="office_id" lazy="false"/>
        <key-many-to-one name="t2" class="Account" lazy="false"/>
           <column name="account_id"/>
           <column name="client_id"/>
        </key-many-to-one>
    </composite-id>
```

but key-many-to-one can reference only primary key of Account and does not accept property-ref.
How to solve this?